# DotNetNuke Image Gallery

Tags: image, list, dynamic, gallery, dotnetnuke

I am looking for a Image Gallery for Dot Net Nuke but with a special feature. I would to select a list of images to show and then supply the list to the module. The list of images will be dynamic.

Thanks in Advance,

Miguel Mederos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this module
http://dnngallery.codeplex.com/
You can configure to do that.

Answer (score 1):

My [photo gallery module for DotNetNuke](http://oliverhine.com/DotNetNuke/Modules/PhotoGallery.aspx) uses either Flickr or Picasa to feed your DNN portal a dynamic list of photos. As photos are uploaded to Flickr or Picasa, they'll get pushed to the DNN module configured for that album. It's 100% free, works with DNN 5-7+, and has quite a few jQuery plugins you can select to control how the images are displayed.